# Limit maze to region

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I have created a random hexagonal maze using an algorithm. But how do I limit the maze to just the green hexagonal region in the following picture? Note that the size of the maze and the green region can vary. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: how do you know removing the X's leaves the maze intact?

Comment: and could you change the wall color to white - i can't see them - thanks

Comment: I can make the generator skip the marked cells when generating the maze. I just need an algorithm to do determine which cells are inside the green region and which aren't.

Comment: if you view as those rows with 4 cells and those with 3, does that help. if your generator skips the marked squares, then you have answered your own Q

Comment: actually this is a bit bright

Comment: You misunderstand. I need the algorithm to pick which cells to exclude before I can exclude them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for even hexagons, but shouldn't be that difficult to adapt for odd hexagons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>
<span id='s1'></span>
</td><td>
<span id='s2'></span>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
ne=1;
while (ne%2!=0) ne=prompt('enter n (even)',4);
gride=new Array();
grido=new Array();

for (i=0;i<2*ne-1;i++) {gride[i]=new Array();for (j=0;j<ne;j++) gride[i][j]=1;}
for (i=0;i<2*ne-1;i++) {grido[i]=new Array();for (j=0;j<ne-1;j++) grido[i][j]=1;}
drawGrid(s1);
makeHexagon();
drawGrid(s2);

function drawGrid(target) {
str=''
for (i=0;i<2*ne-1;i++) {
for (j=0;j<ne;j++) str+=gride[i][j]+'---';
str+='<br>';
for (j=0;j<ne-1;j++) str+='--'+grido[i][j]+'-';
str+='<br>';
}
target.innerHTML=str;
}

function makeHexagon() {
cne=ne/2;
for (i=0;i<2*ne-1;i++) {
if (cne>0) for (j=0;j<cne;j++) {gride[i][j]='*';gride[i][ne-j-1]='*';}
if (i<ne-1) cne--; else if (i>ne-1) cne++;
}
cne=ne/2-1;
for (i=0;i<2*ne-1;i++) {
if (cne>0) for (j=0;j<cne;j++) {grido[i][j]='*';grido[i][ne-j-2]='*';}
if (i<ne-1) cne--; else cne++;
}
}

</script>
</html>
```

You don't really need the `if (cne>0)` bit in makeHexagon().

Comment: Can you make it work with odd values too?

Comment: not yet - i think you just need to make an adjustment to one of the many offsets